# Pass a generic type to Json.encodetostring()

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I'm trying to do something from a guide I found online, which is passing a generic type variable to the `Json` function `encodeToString()`, I do not want to use a `reified type`, but it does not work for me...

Here is my sample code:

```kotlin
fun <G> encodetojson(toConvert: G){
    converted = Json.encodeToString(toConvert)
    return converted
}
```

From the above code I get a `type mismatch` error.

How I might fix this?

Comment: anybody knows ??